# How can we do multiple transactions at same time in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I need to order some inventory then sending the multiple http  requests at  same time from different devices to server.Can we do all tasks at a time .I mean no time difference in each transactions all are need to complete at same time[no sec difference also].can we achieve this in windows 8?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: is it possible ?if possible can you let me know the process.?

Comment: You're trying to synchronize requests from multiple Windows 8 machines to be submitted to the server simultaneously? Can you give a more detailed explanation why and what you're trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Different devices sent the http request to server at a time .They are ordering the inventory from their devices.If they request at same time then all request are need to save at  a time in server db.please tell me.

Comment: Then you want a server side transaction so the inventory operations occur on the server in a single transaction. This is really unrelated to the incoming request and more of a database transaction question that is dependent on your database. You'll need to lock your inventory row, do an update, commit transaction, however without knowing your db details you should post a different question containing this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot control this. HTTP Request timing is not something you have fine grained control over. You make the requests and they either succeed or fail.

Several factors affect the timing including how many requests are currently out, what is processing, network speed/latency, etc. There is no 'request transaction' that this would be enclosed in like you would see with a database.

What are you trying to accomplish though?